# Change the template of Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, html-table

i trying to add the datatables to my code and finaly i did it, however, the template is not good, i don't know how to fix that, is that the problem with my code or that is the default template of datatables?
Can anyone help?
This is some of my code:

```
<th scope="row"><?php echo $stt++?></th>
    <td><?php echo $data["firstname"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["lastname"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["username"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["email"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["phone"]?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
            if($data["level"] == 1){
                echo "Administrator";
            }else{
                echo "Member";
            }
        ?>
    </td>
```

I want the template like this
[image]
This is the interface that i get when i add datatables.

[image: My web]

Comment: The template is not good? Describe how you want it to be improved.

Comment: i wanna put the search box to the right hand side and the button previous and next to the right hand too. i did add a picture on the question, how i want it to be improved

Comment: if you use bootstrap, use `.pull-right` class to pull the search box to right

Comment: make sure `dataTables_length` class has `float:left` and `dataTables_filter` class has `float:right`

Comment: in fact i just add the style link as bellow:
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
So i can not change any properties on that, do you have any idea that can help me solve this problem? or should i download this css file to import to my code?

Comment: The `dom` option on the initialisation of the table lets you use your current CSS framework (if any - though it looks a bit bootstrappy to me). There is also a Bootstrap CSS file available for DataTables. There are some examples in the documentation here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 0):

In the default [plugin](https://www.datatables.net/) it is given as you expected. Hope this may help you.

Comment: giving link to official site is not an answer. please be specific in your answer else it may attract down vote.